# How upgrade my kernel from 32bits to 64bits fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel

I've noticed that when I try to run a 64-bit type rpm package it is not installable because I have 32-bit operating system. How do I change the kernel from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Comment: Assuming your hardware supports 64 bit... you most likely need to reinstall Fedora using the 64 bit installer.. I don't think you can upgrade from 32 to 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled fedora but 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

These Commands Would Fix Your Problem.

---

cat f8everything.sh

!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /yum-repo-mirrors/f8everything cd /yum-repo-mirrors/f8everything wget -Y off -m "ftp://mirror.../pub/fedora/linux/releases/8/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/"

cd /yum-repo-mirrors/f8everything nice createrepo pwd

/etc/yum.repos.d]# cat f8everything.repo [f8everything] name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch baseurl=file:///yum-repo-mirrors/f8everything/ enabled=1 gpgcheck=1 gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora

---

Source: https://www.linux.com/news/upgrade-32-bit-64-bit-fedora-linux-without-system-reinstall